# Can VBA access the data in settings.xml.res in a Word Document?

Tags: vba

I know that Microsoft Word docx documents are essentially zip archives. If you rename them with a .zip extension, you can see multiple files.

After doing this, there is a file located at \word_rels\settings.xml.rels that contains some data.

I have a macro in my Word document. When I run that macro, I would like to extract data out of this XML file, Particularly the Relationships node.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"><Relationship Id="xxxxxx" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/attachedTemplate" Target="http://myurl" TargetMode="External"/></Relationships>
```

I am thinking (hoping) that there is a VBA object that contains this data, but have not been able to find anything so far.

I have tried using the ActiveTemplate.AttachedTemplate, but that just gives me the normal.dotm.

Comment: From within that document?  It's certainly feasible to do this in VBA, but I'm curious what is stored in settings.xml.rels that can't be accessed through the Word object model.

Comment: How would I do it with the Word object model? Maybe that will work?

Comment: I would depend on what you're looking for. Can you edit you question to include the specific setting that you're looking to retrieve and the purpose for doing so? As it stands, this strikes me as a bit of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).